# Issue with storing a file_get_contents into session as a integer

Tags: php, string, int, session-variables, file-get-contents

When developing a PHP website, I ran into a issue with storing a file_get_contents response as a integer in $_SESSION. This is to display a updated rank for off-site data.

I've already tried putting (int) before the response of the web server that I am pulling the data from.

```php
$grouprank = file_get_contents(""); /* returns a 3-digit integer such as (102) */

$_SESSION['rank']       = $grouprank;
```

I wish to store the result of $grouprank as a integer in $_SESSION['rank'].

Answer (score 2):

```
session_start();
$grouprank = file_get_contents("must-have-a-filename.here");
$_SESSION['rank'] = intval( $grouprank );
```

Comment: Yes. The URL was taken out of terms obviously. It goes to a website which returns a set number that inter-tweens to my system. Kinda like a API if you will that will display a certain number

Comment: The response of the API, if you will is being returned as a string. I need it to be a integer.